# how to throw an exception in Visual Studio Web Site Project

Tags: c#, exception

I am trying to create a website that requires the user to select a starting date and a through date for the services provided. Currently I am trying to create an exception if the starting date is after the selected through date. I am able to put the exception in, but do not know where to throw the exception. The code I have is as follows:

```
public partial class CalendarRange : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            // This code will only run on the first page load event
            this.CalStartDate.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
            this.CalThroughDate.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
        }
        else
        {
            // if the starting date is past the through date
            if (this.StartDate > this.ThroughDate)
            {
                    throw new Exception("dates are bogus");

            }
        }

    }
    /**
    * "Get" (accessors) methods for start and through dates
    *
    */

    public DateTime StartDate
    {
        get
        {

            return CalStartDate.SelectedDate;
        }
    }

    public DateTime ThroughDate
    {
        get
        {
            return CalThroughDate.SelectedDate;
        }
    }

}
```

Where should I throw the exception, and should it be in the default.aspx.cs page, or the current page (CalendarRange.ascx.cs)?

Comment: I would argue you do not throw an exception at all. You have a data validation issue, which can be handled with workflow. This is not an exceptional event that you cannot recover from.

Answer (score 0):

If you throw an exception like that, it would stop web page processing. What you are doing is an input validation and therefore you should use validators.

In this case you could use **CustomValidator** with server-side method. More with example on bottom:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx